# Добавить новый элемент в массив js

Tags: массивы, javascript, json

Как в массив js динамически добавлять элементы ?

Например создали сначала пустой массив:

```
var mas = {};
```

а в конце получили вот такой:

```
{
"name1" : val1
"name2" : val2
"name3" : val3
}
```

Я пробовал просто писать вот так:

```
mas.name1 = val1;
```

не выходит(

Что делать ?

Comment: ну это объект а не массив, к тому-же все работает:

    var mas = {};mas.name1 = 5;console.log(mas);
     Object {name1: 5}

Comment: [Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/2bc85ay1/1/)

Comment: Да и правда заработало, где-то в другом месте накосячил значит.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это не массив, а хэш. Массив: `['hi', 'i\'m', 'Doctor', 123];`
Во-вторых, значение (`val1`) нужно заключать в кавычки: `'val1'`. Без них будет ошибка. Только числа без кавычек могут и должны быть.